# How to hide new elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom, google-chrome

I have this code:

```
var $msg = jQuery('<div></div>')
    .hide()
    .appendTo(document.body)
;
if ($msg.is(":hidden")) {
    console.log("hidden");
} else {
    console.log("visible");
}
```

When run, it logs `"hidden"` on Firefox, but `"visible"` on Google Chrome. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried hiding after appending it to body?

```
$(function() {
    var $msg = jQuery('<div>hello</div>').appendTo(document.body).hide();
    if ($msg.is(":hidden")) {
        console.log("hidden");
    } else {
        console.log("visible");
    }
}); // $()
```

worked for me on both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

as eed3si9n said, it was that the `.hide()` call was before the `.appendTo()` call.

I thought I'd just add this answer as I found a different way which also works:

```
jQuery('<div></div>')
    .css("display", "none")
    .appendTo(document.body)
;
```

I don't know exactly if it works like this, but I imagine that adding the element to the DOM with it hidden should be quicker, since the browser doesn't need to render it?

---

An update for those of you who are like me and must know exactly how things work:

The code for jQuery.hide() - comments added by me

```
hide: function(speed,callback){
    return speed ?

        // this block of code won't be run, since speed will be undefined
        this.animate({
            height: "hide", width: "hide", opacity: "hide"
        }, speed, callback) :

        // this is the relevant code
        this.filter(":visible").each(function(){
            this.oldblock = this.oldblock || jQuery.css(this,"display");

            // you can see here that it merely sets the display to 'none'
            this.style.display = "none";
        }).end();
}
```

and here's the code for the `:hidden` selector:

```
hidden: function(a) {
    return "hidden" == a.type                        // <input type="hidden" />
        || jQuery.css(a, "display") == "none"        // style.display = none
        || jQuery.css(a, "visibility") == "hidden";  // style.visibility = hidden
}
```

This doesn't really explain why Chrome isn't showing the element as hidden though...

Comment: The browser shouldn't render your changes until the script finishes anyway, so I doubt it makes much difference in speed. Browsers can act strangely though, so anything is possible.